# generate html table dynamically from json data

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, linq.js

I need to generate html table dynamically and list driver_id underneath.
It is something similar to pivot but the problem is zone_name can change every day.
I'm using jquery and linq.js.

so far what I have tried:

```
var data =
            [
                {
                    "ColorCode": "green",
                    "StatusName": "ACTIVE",
                    "rankId": 0,
                    "zone_name": "Zone A",
                    "driver_id": 100,
                    "zone_rank": 1,
                    "status_id": null,
                    "company_id": null,
                    "updated_on": null,
                    "Driver": null,
                    "login_status": null
                },
                {
                    "ColorCode": "yellow",
                    "StatusName": "BREAK",
                    "rankId": 0,
                    "zone_name": "Zone B",
                    "driver_id": 101,
                    "zone_rank": 1,
                    "status_id": null,
                    "company_id": null,
                    "updated_on": null,
                    "Driver": null,
                    "login_status": null
                },
                {
                    "ColorCode": "green",
                    "StatusName": "ACTIVE",
                    "rankId": 0,
                    "zone_name": "Zone A",
                    "driver_id": 102,
                    "zone_rank": 4,
                    "status_id": null,
                    "company_id": null,
                    "updated_on": null,
                    "Driver": null,
                    "login_status": null
                }
            ]

    var zTable = document.getElementById('tblZoneRank');
    var allzones = Enumerable.From(data)
                             .Distinct(p => p.zone_name)
                             .Select(p => p.zone_name).ToArray();

    $.each(allzones, function (i, item) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var txt = document.createTextNode(item);

    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    var childItem = Enumerable.From(data)
                              .Where(p => p.zone_name == item)
                              .ToArray();
    $.each(childItem, function (j, citem) {
        var ctd = document.createElement("td");
        var ctxt = document.createTextNode(citem.driver_id);

        ctd.appendChild(ctxt);
        $(ctd).css('background-color', citem.ColorCode);
        tr.appendChild(ctd);
    });
    zTable.appendChild(tr);
});
```

It is giving me output in this way:

```
<table id="tblZoneRank">
  <tr>
    <td>Zone A</td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);">100</td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);">102</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Zone B</td>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">101</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

but I need output in this format:
It should display zone_name as column name and underneath driver_id and first id should be zone_rank 1 and 2 and so on..
[image]

Comment: Mapping the pivot not very difficult but not clear what issue is with zone name changes every day? Is that just a sorting issue? So long as property name is always the same shouldn't be an issue

Comment: they delete couple of zones and create single zone when it is not peak or create new zone when they start receiving calls from the far distance (out of all zones)

Comment: OK...so only issue is number of zones may change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not familiar with linq.js so I used native array method `Array#reduce()` and `Map` object to create unique zones

```js
const $table = $('#zoneTable');

// creates Map object with zone names as keys and arrays of jQuery objects(cells) as values
const zoneMap = data.reduce((map, item) => {
  const col = map.get(item.zone_name) || [createCell(item.zone_name)];
  col.push(createCell(item.driver_id, item.ColorCode));
  return map.set(item.zone_name, col);
}, new Map());

// convert Map values to array of arrays. Each sub array is a table column
const colCells = [...zoneMap.values()];

const totalRows = Math.max(...colCells.map(e => e.length));

for (let i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
  const rowCells = colCells.map(col => col[i] || createCell());// fill any missing with empty cell
  const $row = $('<tr>').append(rowCells);
  $table.append($row)
}

// helper function to create cells
function createCell(text = '', color = null) {
  const $td = $('<td>').text(text);
  return color ? $td.css('background-color', color) : $td;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="zoneTable"></table>


<script>
  var data = [{
      "ColorCode": "green",
      "StatusName": "ACTIVE",
      "rankId": 0,
      "zone_name": "Zone A",
      "driver_id": 100,
      "zone_rank": 1,
      "status_id": null,
      "company_id": null,
      "updated_on": null,
      "Driver": null,
      "login_status": null
    },
    {
      "ColorCode": "yellow",
      "StatusName": "BREAK",
      "rankId": 0,
      "zone_name": "Zone B",
      "driver_id": 101,
      "zone_rank": 1,
      "status_id": null,
      "company_id": null,
      "updated_on": null,
      "Driver": null,
      "login_status": null
    },
    {
      "ColorCode": "green",
      "StatusName": "ACTIVE",
      "rankId": 0,
      "zone_name": "Zone A",
      "driver_id": 102,
      "zone_rank": 4,
      "status_id": null,
      "company_id": null,
      "updated_on": null,
      "Driver": null,
      "login_status": null
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, it works as expected, one more thing, how can we bind an event to each driver ID <td>?

Answer (score 1):

So from what I could gather from your question, you're trying to group data items by zone, then outputting them in a table where the columns are the zones. Linq.js can handle this well, it'll just have some problems with transposing the data rows to columns.

```
const zTable = $('#tblZoneRank');
const rows = Enumerable.From(data)
  .GroupBy(p => p.zone_name, p =>
    $('<td></td>')
      .css({'background-color': p.ColorCode})
      .text(p.driver_id)
  )
  .Let(buildRows)
  .Select(rs =>
    $('<tr></tr>').append(rs)
  );
rows.ForEach(r => r.appendTo(zTable));

function buildRows(gs) {
  const header = gs.Select(g =>
    $('<th></th>').text(g.Key())
  ).ToArray();
  const rows = Enumerable.RepeatWithFinalize(
      () => gs.Select(g => g.GetEnumerator()).ToArray(),
      es => es.forEach(e => e.Dispose())
    )
    .Select(es => es.map(e => [e.MoveNext(), e.Current()]))
    .TakeWhile(xs => xs.reduce((a, x) => a || x[0], false))
    .Select(xs => xs.map(x => x[0] ? x[1] : $('<td></td>')));
  return Enumerable.Return(header).Concat(rows);
}
```